# How To Change Decimal Setting in Powerquery

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

currently I have .csv file with some columns have decimal number like 1.0, 2.0, etc

When I try to load this to power query, It automatically convert to 10, 20, etc.

How do I change this setting?

I've already set decimal separator in setting but It always like that.

below is before and after picture

[No data detection]
[image]

[After promoted header, datatype text]
[image]

[After promoted header, datatype decimals]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're in Indonesia where the thousands separator is a decimal point. To solve this, change the datatype using locale (click the icon on the column header) and use a locale such as UK.

[image]

[image]